# Redstone repeater delay if activated

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Can you make a lot of repeaters activate after 10 seconds of making sure it's really activated?

Like, if there is a redstone current that lasts 5 seconds (It will deactivate after 5 seconds) then it will not reach the end. If it lasts 10+ seconds (It has not deactivated, because it is more than 10 seconds of signal.), then it will reach the end and fully activate. Is it possible to do this?

**If confused, read below.**

For example, this is what should ***not*** happen:

[image]

If you further don't understand:

When a redstone block is placed down like shown in the GIF and it removed quickly, the redstone current goes down the line like a wave, until it reaches the end.

What I want it to do is when the redstone block is placed and removed fast, the redstone at the back of the redstone will not activate, for the redstone block needs to be put down for a longer amount of time. Once the redstone block is placed down for 10 seconds or more, then will the whole line of redstone will be lit.

Comment: I'm so confused on what you're trying to ask

Comment: Sorry. Same when I was reading it again. Let me re-write it a little.

Comment: It's worth pointing out in the .gif you don't place it.

Comment: Wierd. It cut it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use a hopper timer

(Terms and Conditions apply, see below)

[image: Hopper timer]

Have two hoppers point into each other. Place a redstone block on a sticky piston above (or next to it), so that one or the other is locked depending on the state of the piston. Place some items into the hopper.

Use a comparator to get the signal from the hopper that is locked when the input is off, and invert it to get your output. It will only turn on if all the items have transferred into the second hopper, where they will stay until the input is turned off. This takes about #items × ⅜ seconds. For a 10 second delay, that is about 26 items.

Note that the reset of the circuit takes the same amount of time, since the items need to flow back into the first hopper, which may or may not be an issue based on your use case.

Comment: It works, I just need to figure out how to connect it to my project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so my original idea didn't work. However I did find a way around it. It does however take up more redstone.

[This is a test of it working](https://youtu.be/CKtfE3UMP_g)

and below is the sorta breakdown

ok so how it works:

The redstone repeaters in your build
The redstone comparator cancelling it out
The other redstone comaparator which stops the comparator from running when it's not a pulse

Comment: I can see it works, but I'm having a slight problem on mine:  https://youtu.be/C7376p4bH_U
Know what the problem is on this?

Comment: yeah, the repeater on the left (not the far left) is mistimed with the one that's creating the pulse