# Redstone circuit that activates on short pulse and does not activate on longer pulse

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I made a circuit that activates on a long signal but I am missing one that activates on a short pulse and does not activate if the pulse time exceeds a certain pulse. Everything I made still activates on a longer pulse which is a problem as I only want one output in a one input system (see below for more details). I would like to have this as an adjustable circuit (minimum/maximum pulse length).

System details:

- 1 input
- 2 outputs
- Longer signal will output a certain signal (x) - this has been made
- Shorter signal will output a certain signal (y) - this is the problem
- Longer signal will not output the signal (y) - this is the problem as it currently does

Current system (very basic)

[image]

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253107/redstone-repeater-delay-if-activated

Comment: Can you provide a diagram of it?  Chances are pretty good that's going to be needed to be able to help you.

Comment: @MadMrCrazy Nope that doesn't work. It just keeps outputting the redstone signal in even after the hoppers transfer the items that I put in. It does not stop after the maximum amount of time :/ Good to know this is at least a duplicate I made by accident :P

Answer (score 1):

so i build a little crude thing that works, it needs improvement, but it will give the idea[image: redstone thingy]

section A is a timer, it counts how long of a pulse is allowed

section B is a falling edge mono-stable circuit

the 32 items in the hopper is so a stone button gets through, but a wooden one doesn't

so when the pulse from the input (between the buttons) and it ends after the clock, it will get cut off

but if its shorter then the clock, it will pass through the comparator facing the piston

note: this is the falling edge mono-stable circuit I used[image: falling edge mono-stable circuit]

hopefully I helped!

Comment: Cool looking contraption! Sounds very promising. I will take a look when I get the chance. Thanks!